# How to make the message and skip the code

Tags: excel, vba, message

I am running a macro that it need open 119 other excel file and copy some informations for I make one overview.

The issue is I did not receive all 119 excell file on the same time and when I tried run the macro I got a error, because macro do not find the file.

I am thinking to create a code that when the macro not find the excel file give a message "not found" and automatically skip for the next file.

Currently if the file was not received I have to delete the code, because I got a error and the macro stop.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "z:\Distribution\Remuneration\Statments_\Trailler Fees \q4\4.q.18 .xlsx" _
        , UpdateLinks:=0
```

Comment: You can use the [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function to test if a certain file/workbook exists before attempting to open it.

Comment: You could use `FileSystemObject` to check if file exists before attempting to open it

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line before the loop (or the `Open` statement):

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Insert this line after the loop (or the `Open` statement):

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

To explain: `On Error Resume Next` will make VBA ignore all the errors it encounters and just keep executing the code from the next line. `On Error GoTo 0` is the standard way for VBA to handle errors. This way your code will simply skip the files that do not exist.

`On Error Resume Next` should be used extremely carefully in general since it can lead to all kinds of unwanted effects. But in a case like this I find it adequate.